# Data truncation [Visual Studio 2005]

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have a SSIS with a Data flow task. In one hand, I have OLE DB provider with a oracle connection from a sql query. Inside the query I have a SUM clause which result is decimal. On the other hand, I have a OLE DB destination with a sql server connection. In consequence, the numeric result is truncated in the OLE DB destination. Obviously I don't want it.

Input query (extract):

```
 (SELECT SUM(CE.CUE_MONTO)
               FROM beneficio2.BNF_CUOTA_EVALUACION CE
              WHERE CE.EVA_ID = E.EVA_ID) AS SIN_MONTO_RECLAMADO
```

CUE_MONTO data type in PLSQL: `NUMBER(12,2)`

Input data type in SSIS: `NUMERIC(38,0)`

Example: If `SIN_MONTO_RECLAMADO` is `4,5` in the destination the value is `4`.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share more information, what is the exact data type in the source and destination. Can you show some data sample

Comment: I solved it. I change the data type in sql server. SSIS automatic asignment of data type give me a headache.